# Можно ли дозапросить права администратора, не прекращая работу приложения и не перезапуская его

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-7, права-доступа

Знаю, что есть способ в старой Delphi 7 проверить наличие прав администратора и используя WinAPI перезапустить приложение с запросом прав администратора а текущее приложение закрыть.
Возник другой вопрос, поскольку большая часть моего приложения не требует особых прав, но есть функции для которых такие права необходимы. Так вот: можно ли сделать так, чтобы приложение запускалось и работало под обычными пользовательскими правами, а при необходимости, когда пользователь начинает использовать особый функционал выдавало бы сообщение, что для использования этих функций требуются права администратора, и когда пользователь соглашается, то приложение дозапрашивало бы у ОС права админа, далее стояла бы проверка получены права или нет.

Я понимаю что такое можно реализовать через WinApi то есть перезапустив приложение с нужными правами. Но у меня вопрос можно ли именно дозапросить права для уже работающего приложения, чтобы весь набор установленных в процессе работы переменных сохранился. То есть именно для текущего экземпляра приложения запросить, не перезагружая его.

Comment: Без перезапуска вроде бы никак. Можно вынести операции, требующие повышенных привилегий, в отдельную программу/COM-объект/сервис/задачу, как описано тут: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/secauthz/developing-applications-that-require-administrator-privilege

Comment: А запустить поток отдельный(класс TThread) может быть можно с правами администратора? То есть чтобы у основного оставались отдельные права, а вот у потока уже администратора?